Which boxes for stucco (new work)?
I would like to install a couple of electrical boxes (smurf tube conduit) on a stucco wall that's being built. I would like to use them for lights, receptacles, switches and low voltage termination (e.g. PoE camera).
Ideally, the boxes are "recessed" (i.e. no surface mount) and they should have a (weather proof) blind cover because not all of them will be used immediately.
Which are the best boxes for this application?

Paint only on a blank cover. Depending on locating the pictures later and then on locating a 3x5" or so target on the end-wall of a house from one is a bad gamble you should not take.

A) "looks nice" is in the eye of the beholder, opinion based and off topic, you should [edit] this bit out. B) "(weather proof) cover because not all of them will be used immediately" since stucco isn't normally used inside, the expectation is that they're outdoor receptacles and that they should all have weatherproof (preferably "in use" weatherproof) covers at all times, whether in use or not.

Ok edited. I also edited to BLIND COVERS. The boxes should house lights, receptacles but for the most part, they will just be empty (for future use). Just at a basic level, I don’t know which boxes to use for this application. That’s my basic question. These? https://www.homedepot.com/pep/Carlon-1-Gang-22-cu-in-PVC-New-Work-ENT-Electrical-Box-A122-CAR/202077343 What is the right (waterproof) blind cover then? Round or single gang? Or square?
